# srand and rand creating same number if executed "x" times in one second

Tags: c, random

My rng code for some reason reproduces only one number if it repeats in one second.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
  for(int i = 1; i <= 100 / 2 ; i++) {
    int now = (int) time(NULL);
    srand(now);
    int rng = rand() % 100 +1;
    printf("%d ", rng);
  }
}
```

This will produce this (number is random every second):

```
86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86
```

Do you know what is wrong?
Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Call `srand` only once (before the loop)

Comment: I am a fool! Thank you very much I was staring at it for like half an hour and was not able to figure out why it was not working.
How do I close this question or how do I mark your comment as answer?

Comment: You are welcome, don't worry for that, let me find a duplicated.

Comment: ```time``` return number of seconds (which is used to feed PRNG) since epoch calling time in a loop doesn't cause time to change unless one second is passed from what i see you either need to increase number of loops or better call ```sleep``` at start of loop and don't forget to flush cache ofcourse (add '\n')

Comment: @KhaledGaber Although this is true, it will extremely slow down the working of the program. In my case I need numbers as fast as the PC can count them. Still thanks.

Comment: @Fajn you are right but it will be more secure although if security is a big concern you shouldn't use these and read from ```urandom``` if using linux. which is much more secure to get random numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seed the `rand()` function before the `for` loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
  srand(time(NULL));
  for(int i = 1; i <= 100 / 2 ; i++) {
    int rng = rand() % 100 +1;
    printf("%d ", rng);
  }
  return 0;
}
```